# Format number with space as thousand separator

Tags: sql, sql-server

First: Yes I know number formatting shall not be done in data layer, but I'm working with  an application I can't modify, nor can I format the result set in the application. I can only write a query.

For a SQL Server 2008 query I want to use space as thousand separator and also round to two decimals. Example: `123363.249999` should be displayed as `123 363,25`.

I've tried:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(money, 123363.249999), 1), '.00', '')
```

But that results in `123,363.25`. I'm looking for nicer solution than just replacing comma with space and dot with comma. It would be nice to set the locale in the query.

Comment: Well, I clearly explained in the question that I can't modify the application :) I can only feed it with a SQL query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For SQL Server 2008, I think your best bet for a "nicer" solution within SQL Server would be to write a custom [CLR function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131043.aspx) to handle the formatting based on region/locale.

For SQL Server 2012 or later, the [FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function has been introduced.

Comment: Alright, but something like the MySQL `FORMAT` function would be nicer. But I understand there is no such thing in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: FORMAT function - I'm listening!!! But neither the word "space" nor "thousands" appear even once on that web page. How can FORMAT be used to "format number with space as thousand separator"?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(money, 12765763363.249999), 1), ',', ' '), '.', ',');
```

It will output the following:

```
12 765 763 363,25
```

Comment: Yes, but the OP specifically stated "I'm looking for nicer solution than just replacing comma with space and dot with comma."

Comment: I have misunderstand the question. I replaced "than just" with "that" when reading... :/

Answer (score 0):

This is also another way of doing it, but it's not really a "cleaner" way of doing things.

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar,CAST(123363.249999 AS money),1),',',' '),'.',',')
```

Output:

```
123 363,25
```

Answer (score 0):

that's the best way of doing it. After you copy and paste it into excel it works perfectly like a charm

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(@yourbig number  AS money) ,1)  ,',',' '), '.', ',')  AS 'SQL gap for thousands finally revealed'
```

It will `CONVERT(VARCHAR)` perhaps must be there otherwise you cannot substitute comma with gap.... I am still trying to make it nicer and shorter but did not find anything else.... here is some [hint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) this but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the most proper solution, but it's one of the clearest in my opinion

```
SELECT LTRIM(REPLACE(FORMAT(1234567890.1234,'### ### ### ##0.00'), '.', ','))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `FORMAT()` function and then replace `','` by spaces and `'.'` by `','` using the `REPLACE()` function, as follows:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(FORMAT(money, 2), ',', ' '), '.', ',')
```

For example, for `1250000.501` it will output `1 250 000,50`